# Why is everything firing multiple times?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, geofire

In my Ionic app, when the user visit the tab "location", a few actions are made to the user's account and the business related.

Now, everything is fired when a key enters (based on Geofire) however it fires multiple time and I do not know why !

For example, the time in milliseconds will fire twice at push and the message pushed is pushed like 8 or 9 times at once.

Here is the code :

```
// Listen to every people in our query...
  geoQuery40.on("key_entered", function(key) {
    // ... and look them up by key ...
    restaurantsRef40.child(key).on("value", function(snapshot42) {
      var restaurant40 = snapshot42.val();
      var displayBusinessName = snapshot42.val().name;
      var displayBusinessDescription = snapshot42.val().description;
      var displayBusinessUid = snapshot42.val().uid;
      firebase.database().ref('accounts/' + userId + '/currentBusiness/').update({
        name: displayBusinessName,
        description: displayBusinessDescription,

        })
          //add the user in the Business' rotary

        var refRotary = firebase.database().ref('business/' + displayBusinessUid + '/rotary/' + userId);
        refRotary.once('value', function(snapshot78) {
          var displayVisit = snapshot78.val().lastVisit;
          var displayCurrentVisit = snapshot78.val().currentVisit;
          var displayWelcomeMessage = snapshot78.val().welcomeMessage;
          var displayBusinessPic = snapshot78.val().photoURL;
          $timeout(function() {
          $scope.displayVisit = displayVisit;
          $scope.displayCurrentVisit = displayCurrentVisit;
          $scope.displayWelcomeMessage = displayWelcomeMessage;
          $scope.displayBusinessPic = displayBusinessPic;

          if (displayCurrentVisit === undefined){
            firebase.database().ref('business/' + displayBusinessUid + '/rotary/' + userId).update({
              uid: userId,
              lastVisit: Date.now(),
              currentVisit: Date.now(),
            })
          } else {
        firebase.database().ref('business/' + displayBusinessUid + '/rotary/' + userId).update({
          uid: userId,
          lastVisit: displayCurrentVisit,
          currentVisit: Date.now(),
        })
}
          if (Date.now() - displayVisit > 3600000){
            firebase.database().ref('business/' + displayBusinessUid + '/rotary/' + userId + '/visits/').push({
              visit: Date.now(),
            })
          }

          var d = new Date();
          var g = new Date();
          d = d.toLocaleTimeString().replace(/:\d+ /, ' ');
          g = g.toLocaleTimeString().replace(/:\d+ /, ' ') + new Date();
          var refRotary2 = firebase.database().ref('business/' + displayBusinessUid);
          refRotary2.once('value', function(snapshot79) {
            var displayWelcomeMessage = snapshot79.val().welcomeMessage;
            var displayBusinessPic = snapshot79.val().photoURL;
            $timeout(function() {
              $scope.displayWelcomeMessage = displayWelcomeMessage;
            $scope.displayBusinessPic = displayBusinessPic;
          // envoie un message directement si c'est la premiere fois de la journee.
          var database = firebase.database();
          firebase.database().ref().child('/accounts/' + userId + '/discussions/' + userId + displayBusinessUid).set({
          blocked: 0,
          name: displayBusinessName,
          profilePic: displayBusinessPic,
          lastMessage: displayWelcomeMessage,
          time: d,
          discussionId: userId + displayBusinessUid,
          newMessages: 1,
          userId: displayBusinessUid,
          })
          firebase.database().ref().child('/messages/' + userId + displayBusinessUid).push({
          name: displayBusinessName,
          profilePic: displayBusinessPic,
          text: displayWelcomeMessage,
          time: d,
          userId: displayBusinessUid,
          })
          firebase.database().ref().child('/accounts/' + displayBusinessUid + '/discussions/' + userId + displayBusinessUid).set({
          name: displayBusinessName,
          profilePic: displayBusinessPic,
          lastMessage: displayWelcomeMessage,
          time: d,
          newMessages: 1,
          userId: displayBusinessUid,
          })
          // fin du message
        })
        })
        })

      })
        //end business rotary
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually told you this in your other question, but I guess you missed it. When using `.on('value', [callback])` you're actually registering a listener for value change events, so it'll trigger every time the value changes, regardless of whether your `key_entered` is triggered a second time. This value change event not only triggers for changes to the object(s) you're requesting, but for any change to any child of those object(s).

What you should be using instead is `.once('value', [callback])` for your Firebase requests (not your `key_entered`-event, using `.on(..)` there is correct).

### Example

Here's the part of the code you should change:

```
geoQuery40.on("key_entered", function(key) {
    //                          v-- Here's the change 
    restaurantsRef40.child(key).once("value", function(snapshot42) {
    ...
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for taking the time to answer, I am relatively new to Javascript and Firebase so I learn at the same time. For the key_entered, I don't have the choice this is a Geofire function and I can not use "Once" for this. Would you mind correcting my code so I can try it ? I am not sure to understand properly. (PS : Sorry for the other discussion I can not not read it for some reasons !)

Comment: No problem. I actually write that using `on` with the key_entered event is correct. But the next line you're using `on` with your Firebase reference, which is what registers a listener, rather than just retrieving your data once. Sometimes, that's what you want, but in this case, you'll want to use `once` (and you actually use `once` in your code further down). I'll update my answer with a bit more code.

Comment: Alright I will wait for your code because I used ONCE at the line you are referring to and it does the same result divided by 2 (pushes it 4 times instead of 8 !) maybe something else I am missing. Thank you for this, I'll wait :)

Comment: That's a start. :-) There may be more that can be done, but you're including a lot of code and the lack of indentation is making it a bit hard to read. You should try to separate your code into smaller bits, e.g. combining logically similar code in functions etc., to improve readability a bit. Future you will love you for it. ;-)

Comment: Thank you Nikolaj, I will mark it as resolved because I pretty much solved the problem, even if indeed I still have the problem, indeed it is probably the chunks of codes that make it hard to execute !